# detecting browser window resize on mobile when switching from portrait to landscape and vice versa

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mobile-browser

I'm using the following code to monitor screen size change and run `alertSize()` but it only works when loading the page and then it doesn't work

```
   window.onresize=alertSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
window.onresize = alertSize;
```

You need to set the "onresize" property to refer to your function, not to the result of calling your function.

Actually you probably shouldn't try this, as it will be very painful to test if your function really is using `alert()`.  The browser fires **many** "resize" events while a window is being resized on a desktop computer.

You might also want to look into CSS media queries.

Comment: thank you so much for the great answer. it works. I will search for that "CSS media queries". all I want is changing some CSS depending on screen size.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries) is the Mozilla documentation page about media queries. They're supported on most modern mobile devices I think, but I'm not an expert.